# sp_addlinkedserver - make sure connection was successful

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make sure that by executing the following code, the server is connected to properly. Right now, a server is down, but sp_addlinkedserver executes without fail, resulting in errors later on.

```
    EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver 'TempServer'
    EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'TempServer', 'true'
```

Following the above code, running sys.server or sp_helpserver shows the TempServer as available even though it's not.

Comment: try to execute a "SELECT 1" ?

Comment: Creating a linked server does not test for an open connection as far as I know. I'm with @AlexK., try running a query against the database after linking.

Comment: Shortly after I run an INSERT INTO #TempTable from TempServer.master.sys.databases and receive error "Could not find server 'TempServer' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct name was specified.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. [sp_testlinkedserver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-testlinkedserver-transact-sql) does the trick. Thanks.